# simple stepper code for scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, binary-tree, racket

I am Using beginner language with list abbreviations.
I have been working on the following for 3 days to no avail.

I need to write a function called step that consumes a 
 Scheme expression (ex) in the  form of an AExp and produces an AExp that represents the next step in a trace of ex

Example :
if the (ex) ex1  is
  (+ 5 (* (+ 1 2 3) 2 (* 4 1)) 7)

then (step ex1) produces:
(+ 5 (* 6 2 (* 4 1)) 7).

so far this is what I have done :

```
(define (step ex)
 (cond [(number? ex) (list  ex)]
       [else
     (cond
       [(symbol=? (ainode-op ex) '+)
          (cons(ainode-op ex)
                  (list-eval1 (ainode-args ex)))]
       [(symbol=? (ainode-op ex) '*)
          (cons(ainode-op ex)
                  (list-eval2 (ainode-args ex)))])]))

(define (list-eval1 exlist)
             (cond [(empty? exlist)(list 0)]
                   [else (append(step (first exlist))
                         (list-eval1 (rest exlist)))]))



      (define (list-eval2 exlist)
              (cond [(empty? exlist)(list 0)]
                    [else (append(step (first exlist))
                    (list-eval2 (rest exlist)))]))
```

But my function doesn't work the way I want it to.
any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a hint. First you should note that an expression can be evaluated when it contains only one symbol and one or more numbers. So you could define an helper function `evaluable?` that returns true when its argument is an expression that can be evaluated. For instance something like:

```
(define (evaluable? exp)
  (cond ((null? exp) #t)
        ((list? (car exp)) #f)
        (else (evaluable? (cdr exp)))))
```

Then you could define `step` that evaluates the first (sub-)expression evaluable and rebuild the rest of the expression. In pseudo-code, something like this:

```
(define (step exp)
  (cond ((number? exp) exp)
        ((evaluable exp) (evaluate exp))
        (else (... make a recursive descent in the current expression by rebuilding the external expression...))))
```

and of course `evaluate` should evaluate a list containing the operators and numeric operands.

**EDIT**

How to descend and build? The last line of `step` could be something like this:

```
(else (cons (car exp) (step-operands (cdr exp))))))
```

Note that we use `cons` to rebuild the structure with the same `car`, and with the result of the processing of the operands by a function `step-operands`, that finds the first operand of the expression that can be rewritten. And since this is homework, I will give you only a sketch of such function (note that I assume that the list `operands` has at least one element, no check is made about the correctness of the expression):

```
(define (step-operands operands)
  (cond ((number? (car operands)) (cons (car operands) (... (cdr operands))))
        (else (cons (... (car operands))(cdr operands)))))
```

You have just to fill the dots with the appropriate functions (and think about what is happening!)

Comment: I understand until the rebuilding the external expression part...so, do I recursively call step onto the rest of exp?

Comment: I modified the answer.

Comment: I am having trouble with evaluable?, it gives me the error car expects a pair given (make-ainode '+ (list 5 (make-ainode '* (list (make-ainode '+ (list 1 2 3))))))

Comment: ok, I figured what the problem was there...but now instead of giving me the next step, I get the final answer I.E : (step (make-ainode '+ (list 5 (make-ainode '+ (list 1 2 3 4))))) gives me 15 instead of (+ 5  10)

Comment: If you use `step` has I defined it, it works only for a single step. `(step '(+ 5 (* (+ 1 2 3) 2 (* 4 1)) 7)) => '(+ 5 (* 6 2 (* 4 1)) 7)`. If you want to produce from `(+ 1 2 3)` different sums, then you should pass `(+ (+ 1 2) 3)` or `(+ 1 (+ 2 3)`. Or, maybe there is some error in `evaluate` or in `step-operands` (check that you have found the right functions for the dots, there are *two* different functions).

Comment: I keep getting (list '+ 5 (list '* (list '+ 1 2 3) 2 (list '* 4 1)) 7) after stepping it? what is wrong?

Comment: Did you put `step-operands` and `step` in place of the dots (in this order)? If so, the best thing is to post a new question with the current state of your program.

Comment: this is how I filled the dots :                                                                                                                      (define (step-operands operands)
             (cond                                                                                             [(number? (car operands))(cons (car operands)(step-operands(cdr operands)))]  
    [else(cons(step(car operands))
              (cdr operands))]))

Comment: This is correct. And when you do `(step '(+ 5 (* (+ 1 2 3) 2 (* 4 1)) 7))` it should produce` '(+ 5 (* 6 2 (* 4 1)) 7)` (if `(evaluate '(+ 1 2 3))` produces `6`).